# Как застилизировать выпадающий список?

Tags: html, css

Есть выпадающий список с чекбоксами. Помогите поправить стиль так, чтобы ширина `.box` осталась такой же, а ширина элементов списка растягивалась по содержимому, [как в обычном селекте](http://prntscr.com/7x5zli)

[Вот мой код](http://jsfiddle.net/xu3kvpbw)

И хотелось, чтобы скорость прорисовки была как и в обычном селекте: проблема в том, что когда страница загружается, отображается сразу весь список, а когда прогрузилась - сразу применяется хайд к списку и всё нормально становится. Как исправить?

Comment: что значит "содержимое отображалось как в обычном селекте"? если проблема только в том, что отображается сразу всё, а потом прячется, попробуйте сделать наоборот - спрятать контейнер с помощью `css` или вообще инлайн-`style='display: none;'`, а потом с помощью `jquery` отобразить по клику

Comment: Хорошо, попробую щас. А как решить проблему с тем, что содержимое не помещается по размеру и переносится на другую строку? Я хочу, чтобы при размере 140px блока содержимое показывалось на всю ширину в зависимости от количества символов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно вытащить `UL` из контекста `div.box`. Для этого пропишем ему `position: absolute;`, причем у родительского `div.box` обязательно должно быть `position: relative;`, тогда они будут позиционироваться относительно друг друга а не относительно страницы.

```css
.box { 
    width: 140px; 
    margin: 15px auto 0; 
    background: #fff; 
    border: 1px solid #C8B5A1; 
    cursor: default;
    position: relative; 
    font-size: 13px;
}
.expand {
    background: url(http://s018.radikal.ru/i505/1507/d8/163953153543.png) no-repeat left; 
    height: 10px; 
    width: 10px; 
    margin: 3px 0; 
    float: right; 
    cursor:default
}
.open {
  margin: 0 3px; 
  padding: 1px;
}
ul { 
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 -1px -1px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(200, 181, 161);
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding: 7px 0px; 
}
ul li { 
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 13px; 
    color: #374747; 
    padding: 3px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="open">Цена<span class="expand"></span></div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="prices_1000"/>
    <label for="prices_1000">до 1000 руб.</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="prices_2000" />
    <label for="prices_2000">от 1000 до 2000 руб..................</label>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="prices_3000" />
    <label for="prices_3000">от 2000 до 3000 руб.</label>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот так хорошо. Спасибо. А как через javascript сделать так, чтобы при клике вне списка он скрывался, а при кликах внутри было всё нормально?

Comment: а зачем имитировать поведение `select`, когда можно просто темизировать стандартный? например, как-нибудь так http://codepen.io/Eliseenko/pen/bdarGM

Comment: но ведь у меня не селект. А в селект нельзя вставить чекбоксы

Comment: тьху, точно. я забыл. но в jquery я не силен. нужно смотреть на месте, что находится вокруг этого селекта (скорее всего это какой-то `<div>`), и с помощью jquery отлавливать событие клика на этом элементе.

Comment: Еще 1 вопрос: как выделить строку, когда выбран нужный чекбокс? Для того, чтобы было понятно, что выбрано пользователем.

Comment: если с помощью `jquery`, найти все выбранные чекбоксы на странице и добавить к ним дополнительный класс `$("input:checkbox:checked").addClass("selected")`

Answer (score 3):

Привет!
Я предлагаю, добавить к твоему классу .box, ещё несколько стилей.

```
.box { min-width: 140px; float:left; margin-left: 30%; margin: 15px auto; 
       background: #fff; border: 1px solid #C8B5A1; cursor: default;
       position: relative; font-size: 13px; }
```

`min-width: 140px;` `float` и `margin` - для позиционирования - тут уже сам посмотришь сколько нужно по верстке.

Выглядит так:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/1ABrPiR.png]
Просто, когда выпадающий список шире, чем само поле "Цена" - бьёт по глазам. Но если так надо по дизайну - то:
 Либо нужно уменьшать шрифт) либо обрезать текст :) либо уменьшать отступы.

Comment: Привет. Да, неплохо, но предложенный вариант не очень подходит. Должен быть фикс. размер, а содержимое растягиваться. Нижний пример подошёл больше. Осталось сделать так, чтобы при клике вне списка он скрывался, а при кликах внутри было всё нормально

Comment: @PoGiS: про «нижний» пример: ответы тут часто меняются местами, потому что получают голоса за и против. Лучше ссылку давать: `[текст](URL)`, [пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/438089/181472)